# What happens if I remove all files from Compile Sources in Build Phases for the project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

What happens if I remove all files from Compile Sources in Build Phases for the project?

Under Targets -> Build Phses -> Compile Sources -> list of files are present. What happens if no files are present over there?

Thanks

Comment: Why ask?  It's easy enough to just try it.  :-)

Comment: Whenever I remove files from build phases, the error "no rule to process file" goes away. But I would like to know would that cause any further problems?

Answer (score 1):

As the warning itself says, the compiler doesn't know how to process some file.

Check for the filename that follows the "no rule to process file" warning, and look for it in the build phases. Then try removing only that file and rebuild the project.

Usually this happens when there's a header file (.h) in the Compile Sources list under Build Phases.

Answer (score 1):

You list objective-c as a tag.  Are your files all either .h, .m or .mm?  - in addition to any .xib or .nib files?

The group "compile sources" is the set of files that the compiler is expected to compile.  Those that are members of a specific target then have the output of their compilation linked together to make that target.  The error "no rule to process file" normally indicates that the system can't deduce which language the files are and therefore how to compile them.

Answer (score 0):

**added main.m and yourclassess .m file into the compile source after below did**

It's very similar:

1.Select the project in the project navigator.

2.Select the Target in the detail view.

3.Select the Build Phase tab.

4.Expand the Compiled Sources section

5.Remove the file you don't want to be compiled anymore

Comment: How do I remove an individual file from Compile Sources. I can't find an option.